# Implementing Generic Repository Pattern - entity key type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, asp.net-web-api2, repository-pattern

I'm implementing a repository pattern in Asp.Net web api application.

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
 {
     private DbContext context_;

     public Repository(DbContext context)
     {
         context_ = context;
     }

     public virtual async Task<T> GetAsync(int id)
     {
         return await context_.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
     }

     ...

 }
```

**Problem:**

Here I have a method `GetAsync(int id)`, which will work for entity which has a single key with `int` type.

But there are some entity with key of `string` type and some entities with composite keys.

**Question:**

How can I overcome this issue?

Is it possible to overcome the issue in a generic way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can notice that `FindAsync` accepts array of objects as a parameter, so you can change your `GetAsync` like this:

```
public virtual Task<T> GetAsync(params object[] keys)
{
     return context_.Set<T>().FindAsync(keys);
}
```

Then you are able to call `GetAsync` with any keys you like, for example:

```
GetAsync(1);
GetAsync("string key");
GetAsync(1, "composite key");
```

Side note: entity framework `Set<T>` is already generic repository, so adding another repository over that one does not really add much benefits.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed `params object[] keys`